# logging program info to file in twisted

Tags: twisted, twisted.web

I have written a code in twisted .I need to write the log information in when we have call 
 d.addErrback(on_failure).

from twisted.python import log
log.startLogging(open('/home/crytek.etl/foo.log', 'w'))

def on_failure(failure):
 log.msg(failure)

d.addErrback(on_failure)

Is this the correct way of implementing this.I don't get any values written to the file.Can someone suggest on how this can be implemented

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to consider opening your log file in append mode.  Otherwise, every time your application starts you'll wipe out all your old logs.  This could make it appear as though the log messages you're expecting to see aren't being logged.

```
from twisted.python import log
log.startLogging(open('/home/crytek.etl/foo.log', 'a'))
```

You should also log failures using `log.err` instead of `log.msg`

```
def on_failure(failure):
    log.err(failure)
```

And you can do this more easily since `on_failure` has exactly the same signature as `log.err`.  Just write:

```
d.addErrback(log.err)
```

Also, I liked, `log.err` *doesn't* have exactly the same signature as `on_failure`.  It is better, it accepts a 2nd argument which is used to present a header for the failure in the log file.  You can use it like this:

```
d.addErrback(log.err, "Frobbing the widget failed")
```

This will present "Frobbing the widget failed" together with the failure in the log file.